# How do I Make my One Page Site's Hamburger Menu Close When Menu Links Are Clicked?

Tags: javascript, hamburger-menu

I am using Wordpress, Elementor, and a template made by Litho (purchased on Envato Market).

I reached out to the template provider, but they said that what I am asking was not included in their template.

From my research I can see that it must be a bit of JS code and seems easy enough, but I have tried every combination of classes within the code snippets I found online to make the menu close when I click on the links.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="hamburger-menu-wrapper hamburger-menu-modern right">
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <a class="close-menu" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-times"></i> </a>
    <div data-elementor-type="section" data-elementor-id="78332" class="elementor elementor-78332">
      <section
        class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-7edd4949 elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default"
        data-id="7edd4949" data-element_type="section">
        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
          <div
            class="full-screen elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-71839b10 elementor-hidden-tablet elementor-hidden-phone"
            data-fullscreen-column-settings="{&quot;fullscreen&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;}" data-id="71839b10"
            data-element_type="column" style="min-height: 671.5px;">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="full-screen elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-16e0b86c"
            data-fullscreen-column-settings="{&quot;fullscreen&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;}" data-id="16e0b86c"
            data-element_type="column" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}"
            style="min-height: 671.5px;">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
              <div
                class="elementor-element elementor-element-16726f6d elementor-widget elementor-widget-litho-left-menu"
                data-id="16726f6d" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="litho-left-menu.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                  <div class="litho-left-menu-wrap navbar-expand-lg navbar-container mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1"
                    data-scrollbar-theme="dark">
                    <div id="mCSB_1" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-dark mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside"
                      style="max-height: none;" tabindex="0">
                      <div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;"
                        dir="ltr">
                        <div id="navbarLeftNav" class="litho-left-menu-wrapper navbar-collapse collapse"
                          itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                          <ul id="menu-dao-landing" class="menu alt-font litho-left-menu" role="menu">
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-76244 item-depth-0">
                              <a href="http://dolphindao.cocollala.site/#mission" itemprop="url">Vision</a></li>
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-78629 item-depth-0">
                              <a href="http://dolphindao.cocollala.site/#pod" itemprop="url">The Pod</a></li>
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-78631 item-depth-0">
                              <a href="http://dolphindao.cocollala.site/#ddaomission" itemprop="url">Mission</a></li>
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-76341 item-depth-0">
                              <a href="http://dolphindao.cocollala.site/#events" itemprop="url">Events</a></li>
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-76246 item-depth-0">
                              <a href="http://dolphindao.cocollala.site/#migration" itemprop="url">Migration Path</a>
                            </li>
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-76248 item-depth-0">
                              <a href="http://dolphindao.cocollala.site/#team" itemprop="url">Team</a></li>
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-76245 item-depth-0">
                              <a href="http://dolphindao.cocollala.site/#contact" itemprop="url">Contact</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical"
                        class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-dark mCSB_scrollTools_vertical"
                        style="display: block;">
                        <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
                          <div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger"
                            style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; display: block; height: 362px; max-height: 679px; top: 0px;">
                            <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                class="elementor-element elementor-element-4d0df934 elementor-hidden-phone elementor-widget elementor-widget-litho-heading"
                data-id="4d0df934" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="litho-heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                  <span class="litho-heading elementor-size-default"><span class="litho-primary-title">Join the
                      pod.</span></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                class="elementor-element elementor-element-43d445d elementor-shape-rounded elementor-widget elementor-widget-litho-social-icons"
                data-id="43d445d" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="litho-social-icons.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                  <div class="social-icon-style-4 social-icons-wrapper">
                    <ul class="medium-icon">
                      <li>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/Dolphin_DAO"
                          class="elementor-icon elementor-social-icon elementor-social-icon-twitter elementor-repeater-item-a073ccb hvr-grow litho-hover-effect"
                          target="_blank">
                          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> <span class="litho-social-hover-effect"></span> </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/Dolphin.DAO/"
                          class="elementor-icon elementor-social-icon elementor-social-icon-instagram elementor-repeater-item-a1c7c08 hvr-grow litho-hover-effect"
                          target="_blank">
                          <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> <span class="litho-social-hover-effect"></span> </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="https://discord.gg/DGuAhdF2pP"
                          class="elementor-icon elementor-social-icon elementor-social-icon-discord elementor-repeater-item-5f7744b hvr-grow litho-hover-effect"
                          target="_blank">
                          <i class="fab fa-discord"></i> <span class="litho-social-hover-effect"></span> </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"
                          class="elementor-icon elementor-social-icon elementor-social-icon-email elementor-repeater-item-e6313e3 hvr-grow litho-hover-effect"
                          target="_blank">
                          <i class="ti ti-email"></i> <span class="litho-social-hover-effect"></span> </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* hamburger menu */

.hamburger-menu-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -ms-ransition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper.left {
    left: -100%;
    right: auto;
}

.show-menu .hamburger-menu-wrapper.left {
    left: 0;
}

.show-menu .hamburger-menu-wrapper {
    right: 0;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu-wrap {
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu-wrap .mCustomScrollBox .mCSB_container.mCS_y_hidden.mCS_no_scrollbar_y {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu-wrap .mCustomScrollBox .mCSB_container {
    width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-item-align: start;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu-wrap .mCustomScrollBox {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .hamburger-menu {
    height: 100%;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .hamburger-menu .close-menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 21px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu .menu-toggle:before,
.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu .menu-toggle:after {
    top: 20px;
    width: 11px;
    right: 7px;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu .sub-menu-item .menu-toggle:before,
.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu .sub-menu-item .menu-toggle:after {
    right: 9px;
    top: 16px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 9px;
}

.mCSB_inside>.mCSB_container {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .litho-left-menu-wrap .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .hamburger-menu .elementor-icon-view-vertical .social-icons-wrapper li a {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: start;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper .hamburger-menu .elementor-icon-view-vertical .social-icons-wrapper li a i {
    text-align: left;
}


/* hamburger menu half */

.hamburger-menu-half {
    width: 50%;
}

.hamburger-menu-half .litho-left-menu-wrap {
    height: calc(100vh - 370px);
}

.hamburger-menu-half .hamburger-menu {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.hamburger-menu-half .mCustomScrollBox {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.hamburger-menu-half .mCustomScrollBox .mCSB_container.mCS_y_hidden.mCS_no_scrollbar_y {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;
}

.hamburger-menu-half .mCustomScrollBox .mCSB_container {
    width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-item-align: start;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper.hamburger-menu-half {
    overflow: visible;
}

.hamburger-menu-half .menu-toggle {
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper.hamburger-menu-half .elementor-section-wrap>.elementor-section>div {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper.hamburger-menu-half .elementor-section-wrap>.elementor-section>.elementor-container>.elementor-row {
    margin: auto;
}

.hamburger-menu-half .litho-left-menu-wrap .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
}


/* hamburger menu modern */

.hamburger-menu-modern {
    width: 50%;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .close-menu {
    color: #fff;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu-wrap {
    height: calc(65vh - 100px);
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li {
    padding: 13px 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .menu-toggle:before,
.hamburger-menu-modern .menu-toggle:after {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li {
    display: block;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li>.menu-toggle {
    margin-top: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li ul>li:first-child {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li ul>li>.menu-toggle {
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li ul>li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li .menu-toggle:before,
.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li .menu-toggle:after {
    width: 14px
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li a {
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .menu-toggle {
    margin-top: 17px;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li ul li {
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 0;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #828282;
    padding: 4px 0 4px;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .sub-menu-item .menu-toggle:before,
.hamburger-menu-modern .sub-menu-item .menu-toggle:after {
    background-color: #828282;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu li ul li a:before {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger-menu-modern .litho-left-menu-wrap .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the JS I have been trying to use:

NOTE: I don't have a clue when it comes to JS and only a slight idea with html and css. The way I understand the code below is that when a link (a) is clicked within litho-left-menu, then the whole hamburger menu closes. Obviously that's not working.

```
$(".litho-left-menu a").on("click", function(){

    $(".hamburger-menu").slideToggle("slow");

});
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I would first confirm that the event listener gets properly triggered by adding a dummy console.log('test') and then checking in the browser console if that gets printed. If it doesn't get printed, then your selector is invalid. If it does get printed, then you may try $('.hamburger-menu').hide()

Comment: ```$(console.log('test').on("click", function(){

    $(".hamburger-menu").slideToggle("slow");

});``` Like this?

Comment: Like this: `$(".litho-left-menu a").on("click", function() { console.log('testing click event listener'); $(".hamburger-menu").slideToggle("slow"); });` Notice the `console.log` is within the `function() { .... }`'s curly braces `{` & `}`.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I wish I understood this haha. It seems like a function that would have come with the template for us super noobs. Is the selector in this case .hamburger-menu or .litho-left-menu? I think I have one or maybe both wrong but it's hard to tell where to start without being sure of either.

Comment: Also, where would the test text show up?

Comment: _where would the test text show up_ --> on the `console`. You may use `Developer Tools` in your browser (for example, in Chrome, if I press `F12` button on keyboard, the developer-tools are displayed). One of the tabs on the dev-tools is the `Console`.

Comment: I keep getting $ is not a function in the console. I have been trying different options as my selector but no luck yet. Any suggestions? This is what I've been using: ```$(" VARIOUS SELECTORS").on("click", function() { console.log('testing click event listener');$(".hamburger-menu").hide(); }); ```

Comment: I just found the JS that is used to make the close button work: ```/ hamburger / side menu close
  var flag = false;
  $( document ).on( 'click', '.close-menu', function () {
   if ( ! flag ) {
    flag = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
     flag = false;
    }, 500 );

    $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'show-menu left-classic-mobile-menu' );
    $( '.sub-menu-item' ).collapse( 'hide' );
    $( '.menu-item.open' ).removeClass( 'show' );
   }
  } );``` Is there a way to make this same code work to close the menu when I click on a link?